# get text and color from button and animate to another activity

Tags: android

I have 2 activities and i want to create transition animation of text and color of one element (button) to another elements (background of the activity & text for TextView)

is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of possible but you have to create custom button so use some layout instead of button and add text view and background color and give `transition_name` to text view so the animation will be held on text view instead of whole button..

You can give elevation to that layout so it look like button.

Answer (score 0):

You may add style in your values.

style.xml

```
<style name="myButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:text">text goes here</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

after this set the above style into your both activity buttons like below

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/myButton" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions!

LayoutInflater is used to manipulate Android screen using predefined XML layouts. this class is used to instantiate layout XML file into its corresponding View objects at runtime

```
LayoutInflaterinflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout
{
    ...
    private void init()
    {
        LayoutInflaterinflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_with_merge_tag, this);
    }
```

To Animate Entity!!